Jmeter randomly getting java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out with multi thread testing
I am testing with jmeter with 100 threads, and in thread group i have around 10 apis.
With infinite loop count, after some time i am randomly getting connect timeout or socket closed exception. Please help me.
With following config:
Thread count: 100
Ramp up period: 1
Loop count: infinite ( with 1 it works fine )
Connect timeout: 2 mins
Response timeout: 2 mins
Can you guyz please check and tell me what is the issue here:
Load time is around 18955 and connect timeout is 0, so what is the issue behind connect timeout.


More updates
When i used charles proxy, to track each request, then from server i am getting 200 response and i see all data in response payload but charles proxy status is failed.
So i think issue only is in jmeter


Check your request outside of jmeter on the same host with curl and see if it connects.

@MortenB Thanks for response.  I started another jmeter app with 1 thread only in same machine, that is working fine. I also tried with proxy server, in which i am getting response from server, but client is closing somehow when trying with multiple threads. Is 1000 threads too many in Apple M2 pro?

No java apps are nice on memory, but as long as you do not get OutOfMemory Exceptions it should be fine. Macs activity monitor is nice to see how the jvm performs. Jmeter also have https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/

You might want to check operating system logs, it might be the case you're hitting maximum number of open file descriptors or user processes, see ulimit command for details.
Also a good idea would be increasing JMeter log level to DEBUG for at least Apache HttpComponents, this way you will know why the connection timed out and who is responsible for that. The line to be added to log4j2.xml file is
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />

